# How can i split String in java with custom pattern

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the location data from this string using `String.split("[,\\:]");`

```
String location = "$,lat:27.980194,lng:46.090199,speed:0.48,fix:1,sats:6,";
String[] str = location.split("[,\\:]");
```

How can i get the data like this.

```
str[0] = 27.980194
str[1] = 46.090199
str[2] = 0.48
str[3] = 1
str[4] = 6
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Better use a regexp IMHO.

Comment: `(\\d+.\\d+)|(\\d)` matches all the numbers you want. now you only need to extract them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to keep the numbers (including dot separator), you can use:

```
String[] str = location.split("[^\\d\\.]+");
```

You will need to ignore the first element in the array which is an empty string.

That will only work if the data names don't contain numbers or dots.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty:

```
String location = "$,lat:27.980194,lng:46.090199,speed:0.48,fix:1,sats:6,";
     List<String> strList = (List) Arrays.asList( location.split("[,\\:]"));

    String[] str = new String[5];
    int count=0;
    for(String s : strList){
        try {
            Double d =Double.parseDouble(s);
            str[count] = d.toString();
            System.out.println("In String Array:"+str[count]);
            count++;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          System.out.println("s:"+s);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks , where the variable count incrementing ?.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String location = "$,lat:27.980194,lng:46.090199,speed:0.48,fix:1,sats:6,";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile( "\\d+\\.*\\d*" ).matcher(location);
        List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
        while (m.find( )) {
            allMatches.add(m.group());
        }
        System.out.println(allMatches);
```